# Composition of permutations is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

For a permutation $p : X \rightarrow X$, let $p_k$ denote the permutation arising by a $k$-fold composition of $p$, i.e. $p^1 = p$ and $p^k = p \circ p^{k−1}$ . Define a
relation $\approx$ on the set $X$ as follows: $i \approx j$ if and only if there exists a
$k \geq 1$ such that $p^k (i) = j$. Prove that $\approx$ is an equivalence relation on
$X$, and that its classes are the cycles of $p$.

An equivalence relation is reflexive, transitive and symmetric.

**Reflexivity**

$\forall(i) \in X$ we must have $(i, i) \in \approx$
This is true by definition, as $p^1=p$, so we have for every $i,i \in X$ $p^1(i) = i$.

**Symmetry**
$\forall (x,y) \in \approx$ we must have $(y,x) \in \approx$
This means whenever $p^k (i) = j$, then $p^k (j) = i$.

**Transitivity**
?

Several questions:

1. is reflexivity correct?
2. in my symmetry case, can $k$ be different for $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$?
3. how to handle transitivity? I can write out the definition, but not sure how to follow

Please give hints, not full solutions if possible.

Comment: I made a rather noticeable edit to my answer; if you'd already read it, you might want to look at my answer to your first question again, since I earlier said your proof was correct (which it is very much not)

Comment: yes, I just noticed it, thank you for just criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your proof of reflexivity is not correct. $p(i)$ is not necessarily $i$. However, notice that, if $i$ is a member of a cycle of length $n$ in $p$, then $p^n(i)=i$. There may be no infinite cycles in finite sets.
2. $k$ can be different for $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ - symmetry would be the property that there exist
   $$\exists k_1[p^{k_1}(i)=j]\Leftrightarrow \exists k_2[p^{k_2}(j)=i]$$
   or, in words, "If applying $p$ some number of times will take $i$ to $j$, then by applying $p$ some more, we can get $j$ back to $i$"
3. Notice that $p^{k_2}(p^{k_1}(i))=p^{k_1+k_2}(i)$ - that is, applying $p$ first $k_1$ times, then $k_2$ times is the same as applying it $k_1+k_2$ times. Thus, if you have that
   $$p^{k_1}(i)=j$$
   $$p^{k_2}(j)=k$$
   what is $p^{k_1+k_2}(i)$?

Comment: Regarding reflexivity: does it mean that after n permutations the permutation "repeats" itself?

Comment: At least for the cycle containing $i$ - consider the permutation $p = (1 2 3) (4 5)$ - it takes 1 to 2 to 3, then (on its third application) takes 3 back to 1. (Which is, in fact, why it's called a cycle). This means $1\approx 1$ since $p^3(1)=1$. But $p^3(4)=5$, so to show $4\approx 4$, you'd use $p^2(4)=4$ instead, since the length of that cycle is $2$. (Though, as an aside, $p^6$ is the identity - it doesn't move any elements, which suffices to show reflexivity for every element)

Comment: I understand that the identity occurs after least_common_multiple of cycle lengths. But for the proof do I need to care about this fact?

Comment: It's probably the fastest way to do it, since you need to demonstrate, for each $i$, the existence of some $n\geq 1$ such that $p^n(i)=i$ - and if there's an $n$ satisfying this for all $i$, that suffices. (Another argument, non-constructive in nature could proceed by noting that $x,p(x),p^2(x),\ldots$ cannot repeat itself without repeating $x$) Moreover, for symmetry, a reasonable argument would be that, if for $k\leq n$ it holds that $p^k(i)=j$, then $p^{n-k}(j)=p^{n-k}(p^k(i))$ which is $i$ if $p^n$ is the identity. So it's certainly a useful fact.

Comment: ok, thanks so much, better get some sleep now and try to tackle this in the morning.